# Cannot connect to remote MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have two webservers that are essentially clones of each other, both connecting to a remote MySQL server with the same username/password.

The problem is, one of them connects just fine, but the other one gives me this error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111 in /var/www/includes/classes/DB.php on line 34 Connection has failed
```

Both servers have the same DB.php file with the same settings. The firewall is allowing all connections to port 3306. I've commented out the default `bind-address` of `127.0.0.1`. I've granted permissions to my user and ran `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`.

Is there something else I'm missing? Why would one server be able to connect but not the other?

Comment: What happens when you run `telnet failing.server.com 3306`, substituting the appropriate hostname?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing something.

`iptables` was the culprit. There were rules added by the old sysadmin that only allowed the one webserver to connect. Added a rule and off we go!